# Why asp.net c# ValidationSummary displays multiple message box?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Here's the thing. I have a ASP.NET Web Application in C#. In the `Default.aspx` I have an `UpdatePanel` containing all the elements. There, I have three validators associated with a `TextBox`, 4 `RadioButton` (two belong two one group and the other two to another group) and for each group I have a validator in order to verify if one element was checked for each group. For all `RadioButton` the `AutoPostBack` is set to `"True"` because when the "No" option is selected for both groups then I will enable a multi-line `TextBox` so the user can input some text. There's also a `ValidationSummary` at the end that displays error messages in a pop-up box and in the page as well. The main issue is the following: if I first select the two options from the `RadioButtons` and then click in the submit button, without input any text in the `TextBox` with the 3 validators, I will get 3 pop-up error messages. And more interesting, if I select after the 3 pop-up error messages another option from any of the `RadioButton` groups, I will get 4 pop-up error messages. I have a guess that it has to do with the `AutoPostBack` attribute of the `RadioButton` because it happens when I click them, but I don't know why or how to fix it.

Here's the code for `Default.aspx`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="M-DCPS 7-digit Student ID#:"></asp:Label>            
        <asp:TextBox ID="studentIDtbox" runat="server" MaxLength="7" Width="6%" CausesValidation="false"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Font-Size="Large" ID="RequiredFieldValidatorAccount" runat="server" ControlToValidate="studentIDtbox" 
            ErrorMessage="ID# required" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator Font-Size="Large" ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="studentIDtbox" ErrorMessage=" ID requires 7 digits" ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{7,}$" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator Font-Size="Large" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="studentIDtbox" 
            ErrorMessage=" ID only accepts numbers" ValidationExpression="^\d+$" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Paper Form:"></asp:Label>            
        <asp:DropDownList ID="paperForm" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Paper Accommodation:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="paperType" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:CustomValidator Font-Size="Large" runat="server" ID="cvIEP" OnServerValidate="cvIEP_ServerValidate" 
            Enabled="true" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="You must select at least one item for documentation on IEP/Section 504." ForeColor="Red">*</asp:CustomValidator>
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Paper is documented?"></asp:Label>

        <asp:RadioButton ID="iepYesRb" runat="server" GroupName="IEPRequirement" Text="Yes" OnCheckedChanged="rButton_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True" CausesValidation="false"/>

        <asp:RadioButton ID="iepNoRb" runat="server" GroupName="IEPRequirement" Text="No" OnCheckedChanged="rButton_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True" CausesValidation="false"/>

        <asp:CustomValidator Font-Size="Large" runat="server" ID="cvRuse" OnServerValidate="cvRuse_ServerValidate" 
            Enabled="true" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="You must select at least one item for regular use." ForeColor="Red">*</asp:CustomValidator>
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Is it used regularly?"></asp:Label>

        <asp:RadioButton ID="ruseYesRb" runat="server" GroupName="RegularUse" Text="Yes" OnCheckedChanged="rButton_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True" CausesValidation="false"/>

        <asp:RadioButton ID="ruseNoRb" runat="server" GroupName="RegularUse" Text="No" OnCheckedChanged="rButton_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True" CausesValidation="false"/>            

        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Provide other evidence if two 'No' where selected."></asp:Label>

        <asp:TextBox ID="evidenceTbox" Style="height: 130px" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="100%" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Button ID="submitButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="submit_OnClick" />

        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="valTest" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="true" BackColor="LightYellow" ForeColor="Red" Width="100%" />

    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="submitButton" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="iepYesRb" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="iepNoRb" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ruseYesRb" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ruseNoRb" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And here's the code for `Default.aspx.cs`:

```
    protected void rButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        evidenceTbox.Enabled = iepNoRb.Checked && ruseNoRb.Checked;
    }

    protected void cvIEP_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
    {
        e.IsValid = iepNoRb.Checked || iepYesRb.Checked;
    }

    protected void cvRuse_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
    {
        e.IsValid = ruseNoRb.Checked || ruseYesRb.Checked;
    }

    protected void submit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alerts", "javascript:alert('Record inserted properly')", true);
        }
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated and critics will be very welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this is true that you set radiobuttons post back true and put them in triggers also?

Comment: I've tried everything, including this last piece of code. Right now I took out of the `UpdatePanel` the `ValidationSummary` and no multiple pop up messages were displayed when the `TextBox` for the ID is left in blank, but it doesn't pop up any error message when I left unmarked all the `RadioButton`, it only shows the message in the summary after the `Button`. But still, I don't understand why.

Comment: In your original code please remove triggers tag and test again.

Comment: It still pops multiple messages when I remove the triggers. Actually nothing changes.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question (I am still looking at it) but it occurs to me that this would be more efficient in a javascript/jquery function using the ClientValidationScript property of a custom validator.  Better than relying on a postback IMHO.  Still looking at your issue....

Comment: You are right Jon, the best way to do it is using a javascript function, but I wanted to know why it is happening that and how to fix it without using javascript/jquery. Thanks and please, if you find anything let me know.